# Wiring CanaKit Relay and Southco EM-05 Electronic Lock

Tags: relay, wiring

I am attempting to wire this relay http://www.canakit.com/4-port-usb-relay-controller.html to this lock http://www.southco.com/en-us/em-05. I have done some work with Arduinos before, but I am not an electrical engineer, therefore I am having trouble figuring out how to wire these 2 together in order to get the relay to power (and open) the lock. Any help would be appreciated!

The relay channels each have NC, COM, and NO.
The lock has GRD, POW, SIG, COM, and NO.

Comment: Do you have a power supply available? If so, what voltage/current rating?

Comment: I do, it's DC 9V.

Comment: 100mA. Forgot that in my last comment :)

Comment: But the lock module has a "typical operating current" of as much as 600mA (at 12V; it accepts as low as 8V). Surely you won't be able to use a 9V, 100mA PSU?

Comment: I also have a PSU that outputs DC 12V, 2A.

Comment: Use the bigger supply!

Comment: Would you know how to actually connect the relay to the lock? I have no idea how to wire the 2 together.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, except I am trying to connect a Raspberry pi with the Southco USB lock Controller: http://www.southco.com/en-us/ea-a6?hid=7336&q=controller It's been a challenge and I'm getting frustrated with it. Have you succeeded in outputting the ACII code to the lock?

Comment: We are actually going to eventually start using that controller as well, but have not started yet. I was able to make the lock successfully open and close using the following code: http://plnkr.co/edit/0NGTAwP7ZG3KQ8wcOXj2?p=catalogue. It's ugly, but that is the serial communication method I used to open and close the lock using the canakit relay. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the lock's brown Ground to the power supply negative terminal, and the red Power lead to the power supply positive.  Also connect a relay "COM' terminal to the power supply positive.  Connect the relay "NO" terminal to the lock's orange control wire.

The lock's microswitch terminals could be used to provide an indication that the lock has actually operated.

Comment: Thanks so much, your wiring scheme was correct. Regarding the second part of your answer about the microswitch terminals, could you elaborate on that please? How would I use the microswitch to determine if the lock has actually operated?

Comment: As I read the datasheet, the microswitch will be closed when the latch is fully retracted (door is unlocked).  You could use this switch closure to light a light to indicate the door is unlocked, or to provide an input to a microcontroller to confirm operation of the lock.

Comment: I want to use this microswitch in tandem with a Raspberry Pi in order to lock and unlock the lock (which is already working) and also to tell if the lock bolt is retracted or not. So would I be attaching the COM of the microswitch to the COM on the relay and the NO to one of the GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: You would connect the microswitch to the Pi GPIO just as you would connect any other switch or pushbutton.

Comment: Alright, I will give that a try. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start by connecting up the power supply. Wire the negative terminal to the negative side of the lock. Then connect the positive side of the lock to the N.O. terminal of the relay. Finally, connect the positive side of the power supply to the Common terminal of the relay. You've actually got four relays there; pick one and ignore the rest.

Comment: The lock apparently includes a microcontroller, so it needs power full-time, and is controlled by the Control input on pin 3

Comment: @PeterBennett in that case, my answer is wrong. Please disregard it.